# Unable to access Ubuntu Virtual Server's ip from host's browser

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox

I have just installed a 64-bit Ubuntu Server on my virtual box running on Windows 7. I actually followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ykt3MeNwORQ
I also did the bridged network in the adapter.
However when I tried to access the server using the IP from the host's browser, it is not working, there is not webpage available.

Anyone experienced this thing before ?
How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: something like tcp6 0   0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 1029/apache2

Comment: what should I do after I opened the file. Sorry for troubling you. I am not familiar with networking

Comment: make that change then restart service using command : `sudo service apache2 restart` then try ip in your browser and letme know

Comment: I still cant access the ip address on my host's browser

Comment: i am looking forward to it

Answer (score 0):

this is sometime happen when your server is bind with localhost or 127.0.0.1 so first you have to check your apache2 service is running using command

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

then check which ip is binded with server port using command

```
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 80
```

if that is not listening correct then do 
open file `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

```
sudo nano  /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

and make change like

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

or

```
Listen serverip:80
```

then restart apache2 service using command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

also disable firewall using

```
sudo ufw disable
```

and flush iptables 
or 
allow port 80 using command

```
sudo ufw allow 80
```

Comment: Both solutions do not work. I still cant access the ip from host's browser

Comment: stop your firewall using `sudo ufw disable` and `sudo iptables -F`

Comment: Still not working. Anyway my host and guest networks are different. host starts with 165 meanwhile guest starts with 192

Comment: but you are saying you did bridge . if you have NAT or bridge then it will not affect if you try to access from host machine but you will not able to access from other machine. if hostonly then may affect . make it NAT or bridge

Comment: it works now. I changed the bridged adapter to host-only. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I can access guest's ip from host's browser now. After changing the adapter setting from bridged to host-only